# How to fetch entries based on contents of several custom fields?

Tags: entries, custom-fieldtype, custom-field

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
{% set vars = "foo, bar" %}

{% set entries1 = craft.entries.section('sectionName').customField1(vars).limit(NULL) %}
{% for entry in entries1 %}
    {% if entry not in allEntries %}
        {% set allEntries = allEntries | merge([entry]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% set entries2 = craft.entries.section('sectionName').customField2(vars).limit(NULL) %}
{% for entry in entries2 %}
    {% if entry not in allEntries %}
        {% set allEntries = allEntries | merge([entry]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But for each custom field I want to check, it's a trip to the database, and I've currently got to check three custom fields. Is there a way to merge these into one trip? I need to know whether the contents of `vars` are in either custom field. They might be in one, none of both, for example.

Answer (score 2):

No, but this is possible with a few lines of plugin code. You just need to create a [DbCommand](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/db/DbCommand) object from your criteria model and add your `WHERE` conditions with a `OR` operator.

Add this function to your [Template variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables) class and you can get the entries from your templates with a single query.

```
public function getEntriesWithVars($vars)
{
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->section = 'sectionName';
    $criteria->limit = null;

    $query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);

    $conditions = array(
        'or',
        array('in', 'field_customField1', $vars),
        array('in', 'field_customField2', $vars)
    );

    $query->andWhere($conditions);

    $results = $query->queryAll();

    return EntryModel::populateModels($results);
}
```

```
{% set vars = ['foo', 'bar'] %}
{% set entries = craft.myPlugin.getEntriesWithVars(vars) %}
```

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but I'm getting a "Column not found" error when trying to do this for "field_researchTheme". I've also tried just straight "researchTheme" as the field name. That field definitely exists on this entry type.